# Маслини - це росіянізм чи питоме слово?

Tags: росіянізм, іменники

Декілька разів натрапляла на інформацію, в якій стверджують, що маслини - це росіянізм, українська назва якого - оливки. Наприклад:

> **[оливки](http://elle.pp.ua/olivki-i-maslini-v-chomu-riznicya/)** - це українська назва ***від слова олива***, а **маслины** — це ***російська назва, від слова масло*** (олія або олива).

У [російсько-українському словнику](https://uk.glosbe.com/ru/uk/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) знаходжу таку інформацію:

> **маслина** - *плід* ***оливка***, однак і зазначено, що *рослина* - "***маслина***".

Там само у прикладах бачу заміну "маслини" у 2 своїх значеннях на "оливки" (включно із значенням дерева):

> Оскільки **оливкове дерево** досить витривале, воно могло залишатися живим під водою протягом кількох місяців Потопу.
>
> Паростки ростуть від одного пня з корінням, і всі разом вони приносять добрий урожай **оливок**.

То як же насправді, **маслина - це росіянізм чи все ж питоме слово?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Дуже дивна етимологія, адже „старослов'янської“ мови нема, є церковнослов'янська.

Але, менш з тим, вживати слово *маслини* не є правильно з тієї причини, що вказана в самому запитані. 
**Масло** в українській тільки одне — вершкове, все інше: або олія, або олива. 
А так, як з *оливок* в нас виходить *оливкова* *олія* (а не маслинове масло), то звичайно і називати треба — *оливки*.

**upd:** [культура мови](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine68-69-27.pdf) дає таке твердження:

> В українській мові від ХVІ ст. слова олива і маслина виступають як конкуренти. Слово маслина підтримане впливом російської мови, яка тісно пов’язана із *старослов’янською*.

Comment: Словник виданий за часи совітського поневолення — 1982 року, тому, очевидно, [вживатимуть](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Староцерковнослов'янська_мова#Назва) визначення завойовницькою, тобто московською, мовою. Ви праві, шчо сучасною украӥньською є _(давньо-/старо)церковнослов’янська мова_. А иншого і багатонаповненого словника не маємо. Однак, про _масло_ та _олію_ було б крашче чимось підґрунтувати, хоч я і не заперечую з вашим висновком. Ласкаво просимо!

Comment: Дякую, підправив. Просто хотів звернути увагу на те, що мова сама в собі має інструменти для знаходження правильної відповіді.

Comment: Згоден з вами і вам теж дяка за добре дїло, слова є [ваговими](http://www1.nas.gov.ua/institutes/ium/Structure/Departments/Department2/kult_staff/Pages/kult_sologub.aspx). Тому бачу цю відповідь як найкрашчу. Про всяк зазначу, шчо слово _upd_ тут необов’язково писати, оскільки SE дає змогу побачити всі потрібні відомости про зміни, але то таке.

Comment: Звучить логічно. Хоча не вистачає доведення того, що слово _масло_ ніколи не мало в українській мові значення _олія_ (адже те, що воно зараз його не має, не означає, що воно раніше його не мало; а ми маємо безліч загальновживаних слів, що були утворені на основі, яка вже вийшла з ужитку чи змінила значення). **Чи хоча б зацитувати саме той фрагмент статті з «Культури мови», що прямо стверджує про церковнослов'янське походження слова «маслина»** (адже теоретично за умови, що слово «масло» раніше могло мати інше значення, і «маслина» могла б бути власним утворенням).

Comment: @Sasha не вистачає, так. 
Зверніть увагу, що Надія Миколаївна вказує також, що «_масло_ утворене від дієслова _мастити, мазати_». По-суті дьогтем теж можна мастити, що, мабуть, і відобразилося в **мастилах**, виштовхнувши використання **масла** у цьому сигменті.

Це суто моя думка, використання **масла** яке _ллють_ на пательню я не зустрічав.

Comment: Ну але ж олією теж [мазали/мастили](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anointing). Тобто те, що раніше й українці могли _маслом_ називати олію не виключено (хоча й не доведено тим більше). В будь-якому разі, я б на Вашому місці просто ще зацитував у відповіді «Це слово [_мастило_] етимологи пояснюють як запозичення із старо[церковно]слов’янської мови. А в старо[церковно]слов’янській його утворено від…» зі статті Н. Сологуб — бо хоч Н. Сологуб прямо не доводить це тверждення, але, НМД, воно є важливим опорним пунктом Ваших міркувань (якщо я правильно їх зрозумів) — ну, але це вже Вам видніше.

Comment: (Ну, просто відповіді теоретично мають писатися так, щоб бути зрозумілими і без переходу за посиланнями — посилання для додаткової інформації.) Але в будь-якому разі теж поставив Вам «плюса».

Answer (score 4):

У [Етимологічному словнику української мови](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) знаходимо:
[image: маслина]

Отже, **маслина** не є росіянізмом і  присутнє в інших слов'янських мовах.